# What option do I check to enable a user role to be able to see all plugins?

Tags: plugins

I want my client to be able to use certain plugins in the admin menu, but they aren't showing up for him.  I'm using capability manager to try and work out what I need to check to show the plugins.  I have him down as an editor.

Does anyone know what I need to check on the role page check options to enable him to see plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Users > Capabilities.

On the right hand side, make sure you select "Editor" from the "Select new Role" box, then click "Change" to bring up the appropriate permissions for that role.

Then, you just need to check the first checkbox, which is labeled "Activate plugins." You might need to check "Install plugins", "Update plugins", and/or "Delete plugins" if you want to give your user additional permissions, but the minimum required to *see* the plugins is to check "Activate plugins."

This screenshot should help clarify:
[image]